# Copy data from List<MyEntity> to DataTable object

Tags: c#-4.0, merge, datatable, generic-list

I have a a List<> of objects (where the objects are a custom entity class) and I have a DataTable which has columns that match the Properties of the Entity class.

Is there a way I can copy the data items with the List to the DataTable without having to loop through the List and manually adding the data to the DataTable.

Here's a sample of my current code (C# 4.0):

```
    void MergeData()
    {
        List<MyEntity> myEntities = GetEntities();

        // Create a DataTable based on the Properties of the MyEntity class
        Type entity = typeof(MyEntity);
        PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetProperties();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name);
        }

        // Here's where I loop through the List and fill the DataTable. 
        // Is there a way to fill the DataTable without looping through the List?    
        foreach (MyEntity e in myEntities)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
            {
                dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(e, null);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
```

Typically, the List<> will have around 27k items so I'm simply curious if there is a cleaner and/or more optimized way to get data from my List<> into a DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

How about making your entities have ability to populate a data row which could be added to your data table. Thus way you reduce the usage of reflection.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I am unable to make changes to the assembly that contains all of our entities.

Comment: Can you subclass it? That way you keep entity clean. Or else write helper class that takes list of entities and returns populated table by assigning values to columns by directly accessing properties of the entity instead of using reflection.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for UserBO
/// </summary>
public class UserBO
{
    public UserBO()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    private string _mUserName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _mUserName; }
        set { _mUserName = value; }
    }
    private string _mPassword;

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _mPassword; }
        set { _mPassword = value; }
    }
    private int _mUserID;

    public int UserID
    {
        get { return _mUserID; }
        set { _mUserID = value; }
    }
}

 IList<UserBO> objlistUserBo = new List<UserBO>();
 objlistUserBo = objUserFacade.Getuserinfo(objUSerBO);

            for (int iterator=0; iterator < objlistUserBo.Count; iterator++)
            {
                objUSerBO = (UserBO)objlistUserBo[iterator];
                string name = objUSerBO.UserName;
                string pwd = objUSerBO.Password;
            }
```